# creating plot matrix with relplot in seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am trying to add multiple plots and create a matrix plot with seaborn. unfortunately python give me following warning.

"relplot is a figure-level function and does not accept target axes. You may wish to try scatterplot"

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5,ncols=5,figsize=(20,20),sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        axes[i][j]=seaborn.relplot(x=col[i+2],y=col[j+2],data=df,ax=axes=[i][j])
```

I would like to know if there's any method with which I can combine all the plots plotted with relplot.

Comment: I am curious about why this was not a helpful error message for you. Did you try `scatterplot`?

Answer (score 0):

[`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) works differently than for example `scatterplot`. With `relplot` you don't need to define subplots and loop over them. Instead you can say what you would like to vary on each row or column of a graph.

For an example from the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(
    x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day",
    col="time", row="sex", data=tips
)
```

Which says: on each subplot, plot the total bill on the x-axis, the tip on the y-axis and vary the hue in a subplot with the day. Then for each column, plot unique data from the "time" column of the tips `dataset`. In this case there are two unique times: "Lunch" and "Diner". And finally vary the "sex" for each subplot row. In this case there are two types of "sex": "Male" and "Female", so on one row you plot the male tipping behavior and on the second the female tipping behavior.

[image]

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but hopefully this explanation helps you.